# How to prevent overriding of parent properties in a PHP class?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, php-7

I'm a beginner in PHP OOP. I want to prevent overriding of parent class properties when child class initiated. For example, I've got  `Parent` and `Child`classes as follows:

```
class Parent {
    protected $array = [];

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function add($value) {
        $this->array[] = $value;
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->array;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}
```

Firstly, I initiated `Parent`class added 3 items to the `array` property:

```
$parent = new Parent;
$parent->add('a');
$parent->add('b');
$parent->add('c');
```

Then, I initiated `Child` class and added 1 item to the `array` property:

```
$child = new Child;
$child->add('d');
```

Actual result:

```
var_dump($parent->show()); // outputs array('a', 'b', 'c')
var_dump($child->show()); // outputs array('d')
```

Expected result:

```
var_dump($parent->show()); // outputs array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
var_dump($child->show()); // outputs array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

How can I do this? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->array = parent::get();
    }
}
```

Comment: child != parent, just because it extends, it's still two separate instances.

Comment: @treyBake, then how can I pass some properties to the child class when initiated?

Comment: child extends parent, but if you instantiate parent it has no connection to child

Comment: Just instantiate child and not parent

Comment: If you always want to pass the same set of properties to the child class, you can just set them as defaults in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using static variable. My classes are like this now:

```
class Parent {
    protected static $array = [];

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function add($value) {
        self::$array[] = $value;
    }

    public function get() {
        return self::$array;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}
```

When I tested it, I got what I expected:

```
$parent = new Parent;
$parent->add('a');
$parent->add('b');
$parent->add('c');

$child = new Child;
$child->add('d');

var_dump($parent->show()); // outputs array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
var_dump($child->show()); // outputs array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that extending a class is not what you want to do here.

You should read about the difference between Classes and Objects. Maybe you should do a general OOP tutorial first.

You need to use static variables if you want them to be shared between instances of your classes.

Comment: Nope a class defines how the object works. The object is instantiated from the class. There are special languages like Smalltalk where classes are also objects but normally the class itself is just a definition saved in a text file and not a "living" object.
https://dev.to/charanrajgolla/beginners-guide---object-oriented-programming

Answer (score -1):

You should do such.

```
$child = clone $parent; 
$child->add('d');
```